# Running a pre-build script when building an R package

Tags: r, package, cran

I have a package that uses both Rcpp and Roxygen2.  I'd like to have R CMD build run a small prebuild script that runs `compileAttributes()` and and `roxygenise()` before it starting the build process. Is there a hook or mechanism to do this?

Comment: [`devtools`](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/) is written to make these things easier.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @mnel suggested, you could use a build script using `devtools`. Say a script named `build.r`:

```
library(devtools)
document()
compileAttributes()
someotherscript()
build()
```

Comment: could you clarify this a little more?  The devtools package seems to run `document()` and the `R CMD INSTALL` when I click 'Install and restart'.  Does it also look for a file named build.r?

Comment: No, the idea would be to make a script that you use when you want to build. The only way I can think of to trigger this using Rstudio is by making a custom add-in so you can use a keyboard shortcut.